# Is this just me, or is the site broken?

Tags: bug, design

Part of the content is lost to the left side of the page.

This is on IE.
[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Which version of IE? Looks fine to me in 10.

Comment: mine is OK (chrome+safari)

Comment: I have IE 11. It's fine now, but as the screenshot shows, there was an error before. Maybe something as simple as CSS not properly loading in my browser. (Also checked FF and it's fine.)

Comment: As I was typing my comment, I saw the same behavior here in meta, but I refreshed and it was back to normal.

Comment: There's something funny about that particular screen width I think: there's some break point that moves the grey version of the logo in the background. I'd guess this is something to do with that.

Comment: Same error was reported by Alan for IE a while ago. They may have just gotten around to it. http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/904/design-bug-in-ie11-on-win8-1